# Behavior of sub-process running in a thread

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, subprocess

Say suppose I'm creating a sub-process from a thread (not main thread).

1. Will the sub-process be killed when I kill the thread? What's the expected behavior?
2. If I want the sub-process to the killed as soon as I kill the thread, what's a good way?
3. How does the sub-process and thread tree look like? How will the sub-process's parent PID be assigned?
4. What happens further if I create a thread (T<sub>1->2</sub>) from that sub-process and again a sub-process from that new thread (T<sub>1->2</sub>) and so on??

Comment: Downvoters, please leave a comment stating why you feel this question is of low quality so that I can address it properly :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified an operating system so this can only be answered in general terms. To begin with you have assume that the system will kill subprocesses when the parent dies. This is not always the case.

However, assuming that you are in a configuration that kills subprocesses with the parent, the general answer is that killing a thread will not kill a subprocess.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention that the OS is Linux. Can you please address the answer accordingly? Also, what does it mean to create a sub-process from a thread? What will the process hierarchy look like?